# Cannot redirect crontab output to file

Tags: python, python-3.x, cron, raspberry-pi

I am on a raspberry pi 5 model B rev 1.0, and am trying to redirect the contents of this simple python program to a file:

```py
import time
import sys

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    sys.stdout.write("out\n")
    sys.stderr.write("err\n")
```

I then added this run statement via `sudo crontab -e`:

```
@reboot /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/test.py >> /home/pi/cronlog.log
```

However, after restarting my computer, the only logs that I see in cronlog.log are the "err" logs.

I also tried this variation:

```
@reboot /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/test.py >> /home/pi/cronlog.log 2>&1
```

and also even tried specifying the log file specifically:

```
@reboot /usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/test.py >> /home/pi/cronlog.log 2>> /home/pi/cronerr.log
```

Neither worked, only printing out the "err" message into the cronlog.log file.

As a last resort, I tried:

```
@reboot /bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/test.py >> /home/py/cronlog.log"
```

And... it still only printed out the err logs.

Any help? Thanks!

As a note, I have tried all of these commands in my normal bash instance, and they work perfectly as expected.

Comment: In some shells, redirection with `>>` requires that the destination file already exists.  Does `/home/py/cronlog.log` exist?

Comment: us cronlog.log a special name? Try a different name help? :)

Comment: I suspect you're seeing the impact of buffering: while `stderr` is unbuffered, `stdout` is typically buffered and output won't be written to the file until you fill the buffer. If you leave your process running for a while, do you eventually see content in the `out` log? What if you run your script with `-u` (`/usr/bin/python3 -u /home/pi/test.py`), which disables output buffering?

Comment: @JohnGordon Hello there! I have checked, and the file does exist. It only has stderr outputs though.

Comment: @rogerdpack I have tried names such as log.txt and asdf.txt, none of which work

Comment: @larsks Hello there! Thank you so much!! That was exactly the issue.

Comment: Why is this needed, doesn't Python flush buffers at exit?

Comment: @rogerdpack The goal is for the program to write to the log file while it is running, before it exits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to @larsks for providing this solution.

The issue was fixed I added a -u after the python3 command. (for unbuffered)

```
python3 -u test.py > file.txt
```